# getting null for @PathParam using springboot

Tags: rest, web-services, spring-boot

i am new in web services,  am using spring-boot for creating web services, whereas, while giving the request with http://localhost:8085/user/30?name=abc, I am getting null for the id property.`

```
 @GetMapping(value="{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public String  getUser(@PathParam("id") Long id,
                    @QueryParam("name") String name){
System.out.println(" Got id by path param : "+ id + " And Got name using Query Param " +name);
return " Got id by path param : "+ id + " And Got name using Query Param " +name;
 }
```

edited to add screenshot.

[screenshot taken from Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/70DKF.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to get with the request? User's name, or any user's parameter specified with the query param `name`?.

Comment: @Boris QueryParam is working fine, stuck with PathParam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `@PathVariable` because you are using `spring-rest` not `@PathParam` that is a `JAX-RS` annotation

```
@GetMapping(value="{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String  getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
                @QueryParam("name") String name){
    System.out.println(" Got id by path param : "+ id + " And Got name using Query Param " +name);
    return " Got id by path param : "+ id + " And Got name using Query Param " +name;
}
```

Comment: why it is not possible by @PathParam

Comment: because you are using spring... `@PathVariable` is equivalent annotation of jax-rs `@PathParam`

Comment: don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @Shiva Did it really worked for you with `@QueryParam`. I don't think so.

Comment: @valerioMC Thanks

Comment: @Shiva that's wonderful. But still debating use of `@QueryParam'.

Comment: Such a simple change. Your answer gave a spark, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are mixing `Jax-RS` annotation with `Spring` annotation

Try this and it will fix your problem

```
@GetMapping(value="{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String  getUser(@PathVariable("id") Long id,
        @RequestParam("name") String name){
    System.out.println(" Got id by path param : "+ id + " And Got name using Query Param " +name);
    return " Got id by path param : "+ id + " And Got name using Query Param " +name;
}
```

Comment: `@GetMappping` is correct, in fact rest-service is responding... `@PathParam` is wrong as i already said

Comment: it should be it put  "/user" at class level

Comment: that is your assumptions. OP didn't have his class level code.

Comment: @Shiva I fixed my answer.

Comment: @Shiva it was quite clear, also because you would have had a 404

Answer (score 0):

For the `id` variable you must use [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) annotation and for the `name` parameter use [@RequestParam](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html).

Here is a full working solution:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

  @GetMapping("/{id}")
  public String getUser(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String name) {
    System.out.println(" Got id by path param : " + id + " And Got name using Query Param " + name);
    return " Got id by path param : " + id + " And Got name using Query Param " + name;
  }

}
```

See [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc) for more details.

Now when you make a request

```
$ curl http://localhost:8085/user/30?name=abc
```

you get a response:

```
 Got id by path param : 30 And Got name using Query Param abc
```